# iView UI dropdown item click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, click, dom-events, iview

I am trying to apply a click event in iView ui. Here is what I am trying:

```
<DropdownMenu slot="list">
     <DropdownItem @on-click="markAsRead">Mark as read</DropdownItem>
</DropdownMenu>
```

The method `markAsRead` doesn't run. How can I make it run?

Answer (score 2):

From [iView documentation on Dropdown](https://www.iviewui.com/components/dropdown-en) you can see that when user clicks on Dropdown Item, Dropdown fires on-click event, which has Dropdown Item's "name" as its argument.

For Dropdown you can use "on-click" event (not native "click" event) on `<Dropdown>` (not on `<DropdownMenu>` and not on `<DropdownItem>`).
So your code should look like this:

```
<Dropdown @on-click = "setReadStatus(name)">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        Mark as read/unread
        <Icon type="ios-arrow-down"></Icon>
    </a>
    <DropdownMenu slot="list">
        <DropdownItem :name="read">Mark as read</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem :name="unread">Mark as unread</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use @click or v-on:click.

This will work:

```
<DropdownMenu slot="list">
     <DropdownItem v-on:click="markAsRead">Mark as read</DropdownItem>
</DropdownMenu>
```

[more on VueJS events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)

Comment: Unfortunately both doesn't work. In their documentation here it is listed but doesn't work 

https://www.iviewui.com/components/dropdown-en#Dropdown_events

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the docs here http://v3.iviewui.com/components/dropdown-en
The Dropdown element emits an 'on-click' event with the name of the clicked dropdown item

You need to ensure two things
1. the name prop is set on the DropdownItem element
2. catch the on-click event on the Dropdown element, and pass the $event as parameter as you normally do for handling data with events.

Here's what the code would look like

```
<Dropdown v-on:on-click="handleDropdownClick($event)">
 <DropdownMenu slot="list">
  <DropdownItem name="Mark as read">Mark as read</DropdownItem>
 </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown
```

On click of the dropdown menu item. You will get "Mark as read" as $event's value.